# How to avoid overflow when evaluating the exponential smoothing function?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, non-smooth-optimization

The exponential smoothing function is $f:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$ defined as

$$f(x):= \log\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}e^{x_i}\right).$$ Obviously, when $x_i$ is large for some $i$, the term inside the logarithmic function goes to infinity. How should we implement the exponential smoothing function in a computer so as to avoid overflow?

The only thing I can think of is to use the identity

$$f(x):= \log\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}e^{(x_i- L)}\right) + L$$ for any $L$, and choose $L$ large enough. Are there other practical(better) ways to do this?

Comment: What about choosing $L = \max x_i $?

Comment: @MartinR yes, of course. This was my first thought when choosing L. But the question is whether there are other essentially different ways to do it, and how do they compare to this approach

Comment: Using your proposed formula with $L := \max_i x_i$ does indeed lead to an _accurate_ computation of the log-sum-exp function _assuming no over- or under-flow_. This was rigorously proven in the [following preprint by Blanchard, Higham, and Higham](http://eprints.maths.manchester.ac.uk/2765/3/paper_nomarks.pdf) (see Theorem 3.2).

Comment: Looks like I skimmed the paper too quickly. Theorem 4.2 shows that the algorithm with shift $L=\max x_i$ computes the log-sum-exp accurately even with underflow!

Comment: @eepperly16 Thanks for the awesome reference! I guess that the shifting idea is the way to go then. If you write a short answer citing the paper, I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $L=x_n=\max_ix_i$ wlog. The function may then be written as

$$f=x_n+\log\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\exp(x_i-x_n)\right)$$

which does not incur any overflow for any individual terms, which are all less than $1$. It is worth noting here that for small $x$ one has

$$\log(1+x)\sim x$$

so that if the exponential terms in the sum underflow it should not be an issue, since

$$x_n+\log(1+\epsilon)\sim x_n+\epsilon\sim x_n$$

cannot be differentiated in floating point arithmetic unless $x_n=0$.

Aside from over/underflow, this form has the advantage of one less exponential term to compute and it is more accurate to compute $\operatorname{Lnp1}(x)=\log(1+x)$ directly for small $x$ instead of adding $1$ and then taking the logarithm. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#High_precision).